# Relations between group Betti numbers and growth rate

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, geometric-group-theory

Are there any relationships between the [growth rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_(group_theory)) of a (finitely generated) group $G$ and its [Betti numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology) $b_i(G)=b_i(BG)$? I'm particularly interested in upper and lower bounds for the total sum $\sum b_i(G)$ when $G$ grows exponentially. Let's also assume $G$ acts effectively and properly discontinuously on some smooth manifold, if that helps.

For a little background: a theorem by Milnor states that the fundamental group of a negatively curved, compact Riemannian manifold $M$ grows exponentially. On the other hand, a theorem by Gromov gives a linear upper bound for $\sum b_i(M)$ in terms of the volume of $M$, from which one can conclude the same bound for $\sum b_i(\pi_1(M))$ (for cohomology over $\mathbb{R}$).

This is somewhat in line with with my (very poor) intuition that the Betti numbers of a group will be bigger if it has more relations on its generators, which in turn tend to slow down its growth. But i didn't find any references relating these concepts.

Comment: This is very general; I don't know exactly what you want: lower bounds, upper bounds? do you have some sample specific question?

Comment: @YCor thanks for the feedback, i've edited the question.

Comment: There are many f.g. groups (of exponential growth) for which $b_2$ is infinite. (I think there are also finitely presented groups with $b_3$ infinite). So finding upper bounds is somewhat hopeless without specific assumptions on $G$.

Comment: @YCor Ok, thanks. What if we assume G acts effectively and properly discontinuously on a manifold, as is the case of $\pi_1(M)$? Would that help? Milnor's theorem and Gromov's bound also hold in this setting, for a negatively curved manifold, for example.

Comment: Every finitely presented group is the fundamental group of a closed manifold(in fact this is true when restricting to dim 4), so it doesn't help in that generality.

Comment: Your intuition is really wrong here. There are neither lower nor upper bounds. For instance, $G$ can admit finite $K(G,1)$, be acyclic ($b_i(G)=0$ for all $i>0$) and have exponential growth. Conversely, you can take the direct products $F_2\times Z^n$: Such groups have exponential growth and arbitrarily high Betti numbers.

Comment: Thank you for these examples @MoisheKohan, and thank you PaulPlummer for pointing that out. That settles the question for me.